How to prove partialling-out operation is linear?
In the Causal ML book, on page 24, the author defines the partialling-out operation as follows:
$
\begin{align}
&\widetilde{} =  − '_{VW}W, \\
&_{VW} ∈ argmin_ \hspace{3pt} E\left[(V - ' W)^2 \right]
\end{align}
$
Next the author posits that the partialling-out operation is linear in the sense that:
$
\begin{align}
Y &= \nu V + \mu U \\
\Rightarrow \widetilde{Y} &= \nu \widetilde{V} + \mu \widetilde{U}
\end{align}
$
The derivation of this statement is left as an exercise to the reader. How can I prove this statement given the above?
